# How to enforce properties with traits on a case class in scala?

Tags: scala, case-class

```
case class CaseClassJobEvent(
                   jobId: String,
                   jobType: Option[String],
                   inPlanning: Option[Boolean],

                   teamId: String,
                   actorId: String,
                   adminActorId: Option[String],
                   sessionId: String,
                   clientSessionId: Option[String],
                   clientCreatedAt: Long,
                   seqId: Long,
                   isSideEffect: Option[Boolean],

                   opAction: String,
                   stepId: Option[String],
                   jobBaseStepId: Option[String],
                   fieldId: Option[String],

                   serverReceivedAt: Option[Long]) extends Event
```

With the trait:

```
trait Event {
  var teamId: String
  var actorId: String
}
```

Produces this error:

```
class CaseClassJobEvent needs to be abstract, since:
[error] it has 2 unimplemented members.
[error] /** As seen from class CaseClassJobEvent, the missing signatures are as follows.
[error]  *  For convenience, these are usable as stub implementations.
[error]  */
[error]   def actorId_=(x$1: String): Unit = ???
[error]   def teamId_=(x$1: String): Unit = ???
[error]   case class CaseClassJobEvent(
[error]              ^
```

What am I doing wrong? What should I be doing? Is there anyway to use traits or inheritance to enforce properties on a case class? I don't want to enforce methods just properties.

Comment: Case classes are immutable by default, thus they dot not generate **setters**. You may prefix those fields with `var` if you need _(but remember that goes against the design of a case class)_, or mark them with `def` on the trait.

Comment: Is there anyway to use traits or inheritance to enforce properties on a case class?

Comment: what do you mean with properties? If you refer to fields, then as I said, just use `def` _(or `val`)_ in the **trait**. If you mean mutable properties, then again, you can mark those as `vars` inside the case class too, but that is an anti-pattern.

Comment: Ah, I get it now, you're right. Thanks. You can answer the question I'll give you the check.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Luis Miguel Mejía Suárez already answered your question, so I thought I would add something here so you might reconsider the design of your class.

Instead of creating a var in your case class, use the .copy method for case class to generate a new object with the changed fields.

So, if you want to change teamId or actorId in your case class do something like this:

```
val jobEvent = CaseClassJobEvent(...)
val changedJobEvent = jobEvent.copy( teamId = "somenewvalue", actorId = "somenewvalue" )
```

To answer your original question:

```
trait Event {
  def teamId: String
  def actorId: String
}

case class CaseClassJobEvent(
                   jobId: String,
                   jobType: Option[String],
                   inPlanning: Option[Boolean],

                   var teamId: String,
                   var actorId: String,
                   adminActorId: Option[String],
                   sessionId: String,
                   clientSessionId: Option[String],
                   clientCreatedAt: Long,
                   seqId: Long,
                   isSideEffect: Option[Boolean],

                   opAction: String,
                   stepId: Option[String],
                   jobBaseStepId: Option[String],
                   fieldId: Option[String],

                   serverReceivedAt: Option[Long]) extends Event
```

A design like this is probably what you wanted. It's fine for a school project, but you would never do something like this in production, especially if you are working in a multithreaded environment. Immutable values are always thread-safe, and you would be breaking that by adding vars to your class.

Just something to consider.

=======

We are currently discussing how to implement CaseClassJobEvent without using mutable values. Here is my suggested implementation.

```
trait Event {
  def teamId: String
  def actorId: String
}

case class CaseClassJobEvent(
                   jobId: String,
                   jobType: Option[String],
                   inPlanning: Option[Boolean],

                   teamId: String,
                   actorId: String,
                   adminActorId: Option[String],
                   sessionId: String,
                   clientSessionId: Option[String],
                   clientCreatedAt: Long,
                   seqId: Long,
                   isSideEffect: Option[Boolean],

                   opAction: String,
                   stepId: Option[String],
                   jobBaseStepId: Option[String],
                   fieldId: Option[String],

                   serverReceivedAt: Option[Long]) extends Event
```

Everything is the same as the solution you want except teamId and actorId are not vars.

If you need to change the value of teamId and actorId in your case class to something else, do something like this:

```
def setTeamIdAndActorId(myEvent: CaseClasJobEvent, newTeamId: Option[String], newActorId: Option[String]): CaseClassJobEvent = {
  val newEvent1 = if (newTeamId.isDefined) myEvent.copy(teamId = newTeamId.get) else myEvent
  val newEvent2 = if (newactorId.isDefined) newEvent1.copy(actorId = newActorId.get) else newEvent1
  newEvent2
}
```

If this seems like a horribly verbose way to have to modify a case class, you're right. What we currently do at our company is use the quicklens library from softwaremill to modify deeply nested case classes with more elegant syntax. It is still not as simple as reassigning a var, but it is more correct in a multithreaded environment, and it is less verbose than calling copy all the time. However, for your purposes, if you want correctness without learning a new library, copy may be your best bet.

=======

The way the conversation is evolving now is that the person who asked the question just wants to have an input that will do something if it has certain fields. This sounds like a job for inheritance.

Suppose I have lots of events.

```
trait Event
```

I want to have a function that only does something if my event has actorId and teamId.

```
trait IdEvent {
  def teamId: String
  def actorId: String
} extends Event
```

Here is my function, that only does something if my event is an IdEvent

```
def processEvent(e: Event): Option[Int] = {
  e match {
    case event: IdEvent => someProcess(event)
    case event: Event => None
  }
}
```

where someProcess has signature

```
def someProcess(input: IdEvent): Option[Int]
```

Comment: Thanks. The use case is different. I am using those traits for type enforcement in a function. The function can only use parameters that have those fields. Do you know of anyway to do this without making those vars muteable?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by type enforcement. You mean actorId and teamId are being passed to a function and is only executing if actorId and teamId have a certain value?

Comment: No meaning any case class passed into the function MUST have actorID and teamID as properties or the type checker will throw an error.

Comment: I think you misunderstood what I meant. I will add an explanation to my answer that explains it better.

Comment: Let me know if my updated answer is clear enough, or if it still doesn't satisfy your use case.

Comment: I fixed some typos.

Comment: Nah let me reframe my problem from the beginning. How do I force a function to only be able to be able to receive parameters that have actorID and teamID as fields of the case class without changing those fields to mute-able variables.

Comment: Let's say the function is def myFun(input: Event) = ???. You set your input to be of type Event or CaseClassJobEvent, and then your input would be guaranteed to have those fields. If you want to do different things depending on the Event, you have to do a match statement on the input and separate it out into cases.

Comment: @BrianYeh But the function needs to modify the values of the attributes? or just read them? - Also, user6337 I believe you wanted to use vars ins your first snippet, since it is identical to the second where you suggest defs.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez thanks for the catch. I've fixed the code in my recommended solution. I mucked up the revision so I've revised the revision. I kept the def in the original solution and the revised solution since we can just pick var or val in the case class itself.

Comment: If you just need to read, why do you want the fields to be mutable?

Comment: @BrianYeh Then just use `def` in the trait, that is all. Why did you marked them as `var`s on the first place?

Comment: @BrianYeh I added a little to my answer, to try to answer your question. I hope I succeeded.